# Is 'to' in "would to say" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, modal-verbs

At a certain point of this article I read;

> Sometimes [Lucas] would to say to Richard, ‘you can't do that’

It sounds awkward for me to see a modal verb followed by "to". Of course, when you're talking mistakes occur, but now I'm puzzled. Is that a mistake or is "would to" grammatically correct?

source: [Return of the Jedi cast reunited after 30 years](http://uk.movies.yahoo.com/return-jedi-cast-reunited-161400677.html)

Answer (score 6):

Your gut feeling is correct: it is a mistake. It should read, “Sometimes [Lucas] would say to Richard …”. Probably just a transcription error or a simply typo, I doubt anyone ever actually said that in the original interview.

Comment: Except for those who read this question.

Comment: Clarified—I meant anyone in the original interview.